# Simple question on symmetric tensors 2

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

This question is related to this one [Simple question on symmetric tensors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920277/simple-question-on-symmetric-tensors]).
 To prove that a vector field $Z$ is Killing, we use the identity
$$0=(L_Zg)(X,Y)=g(X,\nabla_YZ)+g(\nabla_XZ,Y)\ \ \ \forall \ \ X,Y$$ 
It is clear that $(L_Zg)(X,Y)$ is a symmetric tensor. **My Question** is: Is it enough to prove that
$$(L_Zg)(X,X)=0\ \ \ \forall \ \ \ \ X$$
In this case we can say that $Z$ is a Killing vector field if
$$0=g(\nabla_XZ,X)\ \ \ \forall \ \ X$$

## Note

The first identity has three solutions in the plane namely $(1,0),(0,1),(y,-x)$. But the second identity has a more general solution namely $(f(y),h(x))$. So I think they are not equivalent!!

Comment: Yes, this reasoning is correct.

Comment: All books i have read use the first identity @Travis

Comment: That's probably because it is closer to the motivating condition, namely that $\mathcal{L}_Z g = 0$, and in practice it's often not any easier to use the definition that depends just on $X$.

Comment: For example in the plane each equation has a different solution @Travis

Comment: What solutions do you get?

Comment: I edited the Q to explain my claim@Travis

Comment: Are you checking the condition just on a basis $(X^a)$ of the tangent space at a point? Unlike the first condition, which is bilinear in $X$ and $Y$, your condition is quadratic in $X$. Hence, to produce a complete set of component solutions in a frame, it's no longer sufficient to evaluate the expression $g(\nabla_X Z, X)$ for each element $X^a$ in some frame. If this isn't clear, let me know, and I'll write up a detailed answer.

Comment: For example $X = \partial_x + \partial_y$ should show that your $(f,h)$ is not a solution.

Comment: @Travis Could you please explain your comment in a detailed answer. Kindly, note that i want to prove that both identities are equivalent and have the same solution in any manifold, for example the plane or sphere, and any one can use the second identity in his proofs. thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis your $X=(1,1)$ is a solution of both equations. It is not a counterexample.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis you mean $X$ and thought $Z$. You are right, but usually one use only $X=\partial_x$ and $X=\partial_y$ to solve the equation, why in this case i faced this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's compute the mentioned example in detail:

**Example** Find the Killing fields $Z$ of the standard metric $\bar{g} := dx^2 + dy^2$ on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If we write
$$Z = f \partial_x + g \partial_y,$$
for some functions $f,g$ of $(x, y)$, then
$$g(Z, \cdot) = f \,dx + g \,dy$$
and so the bilinear form $(X, Y) \mapsto g(\nabla_X Z, Y)$ is
$$g(\nabla_{\cdot} Z, \cdot) = \nabla(g(Z, \cdot)) = (f_x \,dx + f_y \,dy) \otimes dx + (g_x \, dx + g_y \, dy) \otimes dy.$$
Now, inserting $X = p \partial_x + q \partial_y$, where $p, q$ are functions of $(x, y)$ into both slots gives

$$p^2 f_x + 2pq(f_y + g_x) + q^2 g_y.$$

Now, this must hold separately for every value of $p, q$, and so $f_x, f_y + g_x, g_y$ must all vanish separately. The first gives that $f(x, y) = j(y)$ for some constant $a$ and the third $g(x, y) = k(x)$. Substituting these in the remaining equation and rearranging gives $j_y = - k_x$. Now, the LHS depends only on $y$ and the RHS only on $x$, so both sides are actually constant, say, $c$. Substituting gives that the general solution is

$$Z = (c y + a)\partial_x + (-c x + b)\partial_y = a \partial_x + b \partial_y + c(y \partial_x - x \partial_y).$$

which is exactly the solution space claim.

As in my comment, I mentioned that it is insufficient to evaluate the quadratic expression on a basis to determine a full set of component conditions. If we substitute in $\partial_x$, we get the first condition $f_x = 0$ above and substituting $\partial_y$ gives $g_y = 0$. The solution to this pair of equations is indeed $(j(y), k(x))$ but we can see that this computation misses the critical cross term that cut us down to a finite-dimensional solution space.

**Example** Consider the symmetric bilinear form $Q = dx \,dy$ on a coordinate patch of a $2$-manifold. Then, $Q(\partial_x, \partial_x) = 0$ and $Q(\partial_y, \partial_y) = 0$, but $Q$ is not the zero symmetric bilinear form---so, it's insufficient to test a basis. Put another way, there is more than one quadratic function $q(x, y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose graph contains the $x$- and $y$-axes.

As for the proof that checking the condition $g(\nabla_X Z, X) = 0$ is sufficient, your post essential includes it. A little more formally, one might say that if that condition holds for all $X$, then polarizing the symmetric $2$-tensor form $X \mapsto g(\nabla_X Z, X)$ gives (up to a nonzero constant factor) that the Killing equation holds.

Comment: So, they are equivalent and I can use any in my proofs, but the problem is that one can't use only bases to solve the second one but we can use them to solve the first(I don't know why?), do I understand?

Comment: For the first, you're actually evaluating the condition on pairs $(X_a, X_b)$ of basis elements, and so you perform $n^2$ checks in total (or just $\frac{1}{2}n(n + 1)$ checks if you use symmetry, which lets you check just the elements for which $a \leq b$). In the second, "only checking basis elements" only conducts $n$ checks, which we've seen isn't enough.

Comment: Another way to say this is, if a linear condition $L(X) = 0$ holds on a basis $(X_a)$, it holds for all $X$: By definition any $X$ can be written as a linear combination $\sum_a c_a X_a$, and so by linearity $L(X) = L(\sum_a c_a X_a) = \sum_a c_a T(X_a) = 0$. But if $Q$ is not linear (e.g., it is quadratic) then the second equality in general does not hold, and so we cannot apply this argument.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: This another way is more obvious, thank you